# How to watch for array changes?

Tags: javascript

In Javascript, is there a way to be notified when an array is modified using push, pop, shift or index-based assignment? I want something that would fire an event that I could handle.

I know about the `watch()` functionality in SpiderMonkey, but that only works when the entire variable is set to something else.

Answer (score 217, accepted):

There are a few options...

### 1. Override the push method

Going the quick and dirty route, you could override the `push()` method for your array<sup>1</sup>:

```
Object.defineProperty(myArray, "push", {
  // hide from for..in and prevent further overrides (via default descriptor values)
  value: function () {
    for (var i = 0, n = this.length, l = arguments.length; i < l; i++, n++) {          
      RaiseMyEvent(this, n, this[n] = arguments[i]); // assign/raise your event
    }
    return n;
  }
});
```

<sub><sup>1</sup> Alternatively, if you'd like to target *all* arrays, you could override `Array.prototype.push()`. Use caution, though; other code in your environment may not like or expect that kind of modification. Still, if a catch-all sounds appealing, just replace `myArray` with `Array.prototype`.</sub>

Now, that's just one method and there are lots of ways to change array content. We probably need something more comprehensive...

### 2. Create a custom observable array

Rather than overriding methods, you could create your own observable array. This particular implementation copies an array into a new array-like object and provides custom `push()`, `pop()`, `shift()`, `unshift()`, `slice()`, and `splice()` methods **as well as** custom index accessors (provided that the array size is only modified via one of the aforementioned methods or the `length` property).

```js
function ObservableArray(items) {
  var _self = this,
    _array = [],
    _handlers = {
      itemadded: [],
      itemremoved: [],
      itemset: []
    };

  function defineIndexProperty(index) {
    if (!(index in _self)) {
      Object.defineProperty(_self, index, {
        configurable: true,
        enumerable: true,
        get: function() {
          return _array[index];
        },
        set: function(v) {
          _array[index] = v;
          raiseEvent({
            type: "itemset",
            index: index,
            item: v
          });
        }
      });
    }
  }

  function raiseEvent(event) {
    _handlers[event.type].forEach(function(h) {
      h.call(_self, event);
    });
  }

  Object.defineProperty(_self, "addEventListener", {
    configurable: false,
    enumerable: false,
    writable: false,
    value: function(eventName, handler) {
      eventName = ("" + eventName).toLowerCase();
      if (!(eventName in _handlers)) throw new Error("Invalid event name.");
      if (typeof handler !== "function") throw new Error("Invalid handler.");
      _handlers[eventName].push(handler);
    }
  });

  Object.defineProperty(_self, "removeEventListener", {
    configurable: false,
    enumerable: false,
    writable: false,
    value: function(eventName, handler) {
      eventName = ("" + eventName).toLowerCase();
      if (!(eventName in _handlers)) throw new Error("Invalid event name.");
      if (typeof handler !== "function") throw new Error("Invalid handler.");
      var h = _handlers[eventName];
      var ln = h.length;
      while (--ln >= 0) {
        if (h[ln] === handler) {
          h.splice(ln, 1);
        }
      }
    }
  });

  Object.defineProperty(_self, "push", {
    configurable: false,
    enumerable: false,
    writable: false,
    value: function() {
      var index;
      for (var i = 0, ln = arguments.length; i < ln; i++) {
        index = _array.length;
        _array.push(arguments[i]);
        defineIndexProperty(index);
        raiseEvent({
          type: "itemadded",
          index: index,
          item: arguments[i]
        });
      }
      return _array.length;
    }
  });

  Object.defineProperty(_self, "pop", {
    configurable: false,
    enumerable: false,
    writable: false,
    value: function() {
      if (_array.length > -1) {
        var index = _array.length - 1,
          item = _array.pop();
        delete _self[index];
        raiseEvent({
          type: "itemremoved",
          index: index,
          item: item
        });
        return item;
      }
    }
  });

  Object.defineProperty(_self, "unshift", {
    configurable: false,
    enumerable: false,
    writable: false,
    value: function() {
      for (var i = 0, ln = arguments.length; i < ln; i++) {
        _array.splice(i, 0, arguments[i]);
        defineIndexProperty(_array.length - 1);
        raiseEvent({
          type: "itemadded",
          index: i,
          item: arguments[i]
        });
      }
      for (; i < _array.length; i++) {
        raiseEvent({
          type: "itemset",
          index: i,
          item: _array[i]
        });
      }
      return _array.length;
    }
  });

  Object.defineProperty(_self, "shift", {
    configurable: false,
    enumerable: false,
    writable: false,
    value: function() {
      if (_array.length > -1) {
        var item = _array.shift();
        delete _self[_array.length];
        raiseEvent({
          type: "itemremoved",
          index: 0,
          item: item
        });
        return item;
      }
    }
  });

  Object.defineProperty(_self, "splice", {
    configurable: false,
    enumerable: false,
    writable: false,
    value: function(index, howMany /*, element1, element2, ... */ ) {
      var removed = [],
          item,
          pos;

      index = index == null ? 0 : index < 0 ? _array.length + index : index;

      howMany = howMany == null ? _array.length - index : howMany > 0 ? howMany : 0;

      while (howMany--) {
        item = _array.splice(index, 1)[0];
        removed.push(item);
        delete _self[_array.length];
        raiseEvent({
          type: "itemremoved",
          index: index + removed.length - 1,
          item: item
        });
      }

      for (var i = 2, ln = arguments.length; i < ln; i++) {
        _array.splice(index, 0, arguments[i]);
        defineIndexProperty(_array.length - 1);
        raiseEvent({
          type: "itemadded",
          index: index,
          item: arguments[i]
        });
        index++;
      }

      return removed;
    }
  });

  Object.defineProperty(_self, "length", {
    configurable: false,
    enumerable: false,
    get: function() {
      return _array.length;
    },
    set: function(value) {
      var n = Number(value);
      var length = _array.length;
      if (n % 1 === 0 && n >= 0) {        
        if (n < length) {
          _self.splice(n);
        } else if (n > length) {
          _self.push.apply(_self, new Array(n - length));
        }
      } else {
        throw new RangeError("Invalid array length");
      }
      _array.length = n;
      return value;
    }
  });

  Object.getOwnPropertyNames(Array.prototype).forEach(function(name) {
    if (!(name in _self)) {
      Object.defineProperty(_self, name, {
        configurable: false,
        enumerable: false,
        writable: false,
        value: Array.prototype[name]
      });
    }
  });

  if (items instanceof Array) {
    _self.push.apply(_self, items);
  }
}

(function testing() {

  var x = new ObservableArray(["a", "b", "c", "d"]);

  console.log("original array: %o", x.slice());

  x.addEventListener("itemadded", function(e) {
    console.log("Added %o at index %d.", e.item, e.index);
  });

  x.addEventListener("itemset", function(e) {
    console.log("Set index %d to %o.", e.index, e.item);
  });

  x.addEventListener("itemremoved", function(e) {
    console.log("Removed %o at index %d.", e.item, e.index);
  });
 
  console.log("popping and unshifting...");
  x.unshift(x.pop());

  console.log("updated array: %o", x.slice());

  console.log("reversing array...");
  console.log("updated array: %o", x.reverse().slice());

  console.log("splicing...");
  x.splice(1, 2, "x");
  console.log("setting index 2...");
  x[2] = "foo";

  console.log("setting length to 10...");
  x.length = 10;
  console.log("updated array: %o", x.slice());

  console.log("setting length to 2...");
  x.length = 2;

  console.log("extracting first element via shift()");
  x.shift();

  console.log("updated array: %o", x.slice());

})();
```

<sub>See `Object.defineProperty()` for reference.</sub>

That gets us closer but it's still not bullet proof... which brings us to:

### 3. Proxies

A [Proxy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) object offers another solution to [the modern browser](https://caniuse.com/proxy). It allows you to intercept method calls, accessors, etc. Most importantly, you can do this without even providing an explicit property name... which would allow you to test for an arbitrary, index-based access/assignment. You can even intercept property deletion. Proxies would effectively allow you to inspect a change *before* deciding to allow it... in addition to handling the change after the fact.

Here's a stripped down sample:

```js
(function() {

  if (!("Proxy" in window)) {
    console.warn("Your browser doesn't support Proxies.");
    return;
  }

  // our backing array
  var array = ["a", "b", "c", "d"];

  // a proxy for our array
  var proxy = new Proxy(array, {
    deleteProperty: function(target, property) {
      delete target[property];
      console.log("Deleted %s", property);
      return true;
    },
    set: function(target, property, value, receiver) {      
      target[property] = value;
      console.log("Set %s to %o", property, value);
      return true;
    }
  });

  console.log("Set a specific index..");
  proxy[0] = "x";

  console.log("Add via push()...");
  proxy.push("z");

  console.log("Add/remove via splice()...");
  proxy.splice(1, 3, "y");

  console.log("Current state of array: %o", array);

})();
```

Comment: Thanks! That works for the regular array methods. Any ideas on how to raise an event for something like "arr[2] = "foo" ?

Comment: I guess you could implement a method `set(index)` in Array's prototype and do something like antisanity says

Comment: It would be much better to subclass Array. It's generally not a good idea to modify Array's prototype.

Comment: Outstanding answer here. The ObservableArray's class is excellent. +1

Comment: "'_array.length === 0 && delete _self[index];" - can you explain this line?

Comment: Here is another bug - `shift()` is calling `defineIndexProperty` with index, instead of the index of the newly added item. I think defineIndexProperty can be changed to always add the last index, as this is what's added.

Comment: Oh, I missed that, sorry.
One more thing - in `splice`, in the line`index = !~index ? _array.length - index : index;` - shouldn't `!~index` be replaced with `index < 0`?

Comment: I executed the code of the Proxy example, implementing the `deleteProperty`, `set` and `get` traps adding some `console.log`s. Those traps are called 12 times just for the `splice` method! Is it performance-compliant to implement a change handler with a proxy?

Comment: @canon In my case, it would be generic handlers : actions performed when an item is added / deleted. Filter and sync with another object, AJAX stuff...

Comment: Taking into account the return value of `Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(Array.prototype, "push")`, `writtable` and `configurable` should be set to `true`.

Comment: @canon yeah, my intention was to make it as transparent as possible i.e. have the least possible side effects, so I added a new answer based on yours.

Comment: Thanks for these examples! It seems in Proxy there is unnecessary `apply` [trap](https://devdocs.io/javascript/global_objects/proxy/proxy/apply) or I don't fully understand why it is needed. Because `set` and `deleteProperty` cover all cases of array modifications.

Comment: Thanks for this - excellent!  One thing I'm confused about, though: in the Proxy example, how come `set` needs to be implemented (to change the value) but `deleteProperty` does not?

Comment: @IpsRich That was an oversight. Once the length of an array is modified, almost anything which visualizes or serializes it is going to ignore indices beyond the new length. It would have been more obvious with an object. Updated. ;)

Comment: @canon Thanks for the update.  It just confused me because it seems to work fine without the explicit `delete` but not without the explicit set!

Comment: @canon Quick update...  I realised that when working with arrays, `delete` doesn't tend to be used directly, anyway; indeed, doing something like `delete array[1]` just replaces element 1's value with `undefined` which isn't terribly useful!  So I was able to safely remove all of the `deleteProperty` code without any functional degradation. During a `shift` call, it doesn't matter that the last element is not removed (because `deleteProperty` isn't now implemented), because setting the `length` property has the effect of deleting the last element anyway! Thanks again for the excellent answer.

Comment: A good thing to know about the proxy approach is that after `delete target[property];`, the length property wont be updated yet

Comment: That doesn't have anything to do with proxies, that's just how `delete` works; it doesn't modify array length. Consider: `{ const x = [1337]; delete x[0]; console.log(x.length); /* output: 1 */ }`. `length` is still `1` after deleting the only index property. In the context of a compound operation, something like `splice()` would handle setting `length` after applying its mutations.

Answer (score 32):

From reading all the answers here, I have assembled a simplified solution that does not require any external libraries.

It also illustrates much better the general idea for the approach:

```
function processQ() {
   // ... this will be called on each .push
}

var myEventsQ = [];
myEventsQ.push = function() { Array.prototype.push.apply(this, arguments);  processQ();};
```

Comment: This is good idea, but don't you think that if for example I want to implement this in chart js data arrays, and I have 50 charts which means 50 arrays and each array will be updated every second --> imagine the size of the 'myEventsQ' array at the end of the day!
I think when need to shift it every now and then

Comment: You don't understand the solution. myEventsQ IS the array (one of your 50 arrays). This snippet does not change the size of array, and does not add any additional arrays, it only changes prototype of the existing ones.

Comment: mmmm I see, more explanation should have been provided though!

Comment: `push` returns the `length` of the array. So, you can get the value returned by  `Array.prototype.push.apply` to a variable and return it from the custom `push` function.

Answer (score 23):

I used the following code to listen to changes to an array.

```
/* @arr array you want to listen to
   @callback function that will be called on any change inside array
 */
function listenChangesinArray(arr,callback){
     // Add more methods here if you want to listen to them
    ['pop','push','reverse','shift','unshift','splice','sort'].forEach((m)=>{
        arr[m] = function(){
                     var res = Array.prototype[m].apply(arr, arguments);  // call normal behaviour
                     callback.apply(arr, arguments);  // finally call the callback supplied
                     return res;
                 }
    });
}
```

Hope this was useful :)

Answer (score 12):

I found the following which seems to accomplish this:
https://github.com/mennovanslooten/Observable-Arrays

Observable-Arrays extends underscore and can be used as follow:
(from that page)

```
// For example, take any array:
var a = ['zero', 'one', 'two', 'trhee'];

// Add a generic observer function to that array:
_.observe(a, function() {
    alert('something happened');
});
```

Comment: This is great, but there's an important caveat: when an array is modified like `arr[2] = "foo"`, the change notification is _asynchronous_. Since JS doesn't provide any way to watch for such changes, this library relies on a timeout that runs every 250 ms and checks to see if the array has changed at all -- so you won't get a change notification until the next time the timeout runs.  Other changes like `push()` get notified immediately (synchronously), however.

Comment: Also I guess 250 interval will affect your site performance if the array is big.

Comment: Just used this, works like a charm. For our node-based friends I used this incantation with a promise.(format in comments is a pain...)


    _ = require('lodash');
    require("underscore-observe")(_);
    Promise = require("bluebird");
    
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
      return _.observe(queue, 'delete', function() {
        if (_.isEmpty(queue)) {
          return resolve(action);
        }
      });
    });

Answer (score 7):

The most upvoted **Override push method** solution by @canon has some side-effects that were inconvenient in my case:

- It makes the push property descriptor different (`writable` and `configurable` should be set `true` instead of `false`), which causes exceptions in a later point.
- It raises the event multiple times when `push()` is called once with multiple arguments (such as `myArray.push("a", "b")`), which in my case was unnecessary and bad for performance.

So this is the best solution I could find that fixes the previous issues and is in my opinion cleaner/simpler/easier to understand.

```
Object.defineProperty(myArray, "push", {
    configurable: true,
    enumerable: false,
    writable: true, // Previous values based on Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(Array.prototype, "push")
    value: function (...args)
    {
        let result = Array.prototype.push.apply(this, args); // Original push() implementation based on https://github.com/vuejs/vue/blob/f2b476d4f4f685d84b4957e6c805740597945cde/src/core/observer/array.js and https://github.com/vuejs/vue/blob/daed1e73557d57df244ad8d46c9afff7208c9a2d/src/core/util/lang.js

        RaiseMyEvent();

        return result; // Original push() implementation
    }
});
```

Please see comments for my sources and for hints on how to implement the other mutating functions apart from push: 'pop', 'shift', 'unshift', 'splice', 'sort', 'reverse'.

Comment: @canon I do have Proxies available, but I cannot use them because the array is modified externally, and I can't think of any way to force the external callers (which besides change from time to time without my control) to use a Proxy.

Comment: @canon and by the way, your comment made me make a wrong assumption, which is that I'm using the spread operator, when actually I'm not. So no, I'm not leveraging the spread operator at all. What I'm using is the rest parameter which has a similar `...` syntax, and which can be easily replaced with the use of the `arguments` keyword.

Comment: Those links are...: https://github.com/vuejs/vue/blob/f2b476d4f4f685d84b4957e6c805740597945cde/src/core/observer/array.js https://github.com/vuejs/vue/blob/daed1e73557d57df244ad8d46c9afff7208c9a2d/src/core/util/lang.js

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this covers absolutely everything, but I use something like this (especially when debugging) to detect when an array has an element added:

```
var array = [1,2,3,4];
array = new Proxy(array, {
    set: function(target, key, value) {
        if (Number.isInteger(Number(key)) || key === 'length') {
            debugger; //or other code
        }
        target[key] = value;
        return true;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (!Array.prototype.forEach)
{
    Object.defineProperty(Array.prototype, 'forEach',
    {
        enumerable: false,
        value: function(callback)
        {
            for(var index = 0; index != this.length; index++) { callback(this[index], index, this); }
        }
    });
}

if(Object.observe)
{
    Object.defineProperty(Array.prototype, 'Observe',
    {
        set: function(callback)
        {
            Object.observe(this, function(changes)
            {
                changes.forEach(function(change)
                {
                    if(change.type == 'update') { callback(); }
                });
            });
        }
    });
}
else
{
    Object.defineProperties(Array.prototype,
    { 
        onchange: { enumerable: false, writable: true, value: function() { } },
        Observe:
        {
            set: function(callback)
            {
                Object.defineProperty(this, 'onchange', { enumerable: false, writable: true, value: callback }); 
            }
        }
    });

    var names = ['push', 'pop', 'reverse', 'shift', 'unshift'];
    names.forEach(function(name)
    {
        if(!(name in Array.prototype)) { return; }
        var pointer = Array.prototype[name];
        Array.prototype[name] = function()
        {
            pointer.apply(this, arguments); 
            this.onchange();
        }
    });
}

var a = [1, 2, 3];
a.Observe = function() { console.log("Array changed!"); };
a.push(8);
```

Comment: Looks like `Object.observe()` and `Array.observe()` were withdrawn from the spec. Support has already been pulled from Chrome. :/

Answer (score -1):

An interesting collection library is https://github.com/mgesmundo/smart-collection. Allows you to watch arrays and add views to them as well. Not sure about the performance as I am testing it out myself. Will update this post soon.

Answer (score -2):

I fiddled around and came up with this. The idea is that the object has all the Array.prototype methods defined, but executes them on a separate array object. This gives the ability to observe methods like shift(), pop() etc. Although some methods like concat() won't return the OArray object. Overloading those methods won't make the object observable if accessors are used. To achieve the latter, the accessors are defined for each index within given capacity.

Performance wise... OArray is around 10-25 times slower compared to the plain Array object. For the capasity in a range 1 - 100 the difference is 1x-3x.

```
class OArray {
    constructor(capacity, observer) {

        var Obj = {};
        var Ref = []; // reference object to hold values and apply array methods

        if (!observer) observer = function noop() {};

        var propertyDescriptors = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors(Array.prototype);

        Object.keys(propertyDescriptors).forEach(function(property) {
            // the property will be binded to Obj, but applied on Ref!

            var descriptor = propertyDescriptors[property];
            var attributes = {
                configurable: descriptor.configurable,
                enumerable: descriptor.enumerable,
                writable: descriptor.writable,
                value: function() {
                    observer.call({});
                    return descriptor.value.apply(Ref, arguments);
                }
            };
            // exception to length
            if (property === 'length') {
                delete attributes.value;
                delete attributes.writable;
                attributes.get = function() {
                    return Ref.length
                };
                attributes.set = function(length) {
                    Ref.length = length;
                };
            }

            Object.defineProperty(Obj, property, attributes);
        });

        var indexerProperties = {};
        for (var k = 0; k < capacity; k++) {

            indexerProperties[k] = {
                configurable: true,
                get: (function() {
                    var _i = k;
                    return function() {
                        return Ref[_i];
                    }
                })(),
                set: (function() {
                    var _i = k;
                    return function(value) {
                        Ref[_i] = value;
                        observer.call({});
                        return true;
                    }
                })()
            };
        }
        Object.defineProperties(Obj, indexerProperties);

        return Obj;
    }
}
```

Comment: While it works on existing elements, it does not work when an element is added with array[new_index] = value. Only proxies can do that.

Answer (score -6):

I wouldn't recommend you to extend native prototypes. Instead, you can use a library like new-list; https://github.com/azer/new-list

It creates a native JavaScript array and lets you subscribe to any change. It batches the updates and gives you the final diff;

```
List = require('new-list')
todo = List('Buy milk', 'Take shower')

todo.pop()
todo.push('Cook Dinner')
todo.splice(0, 1, 'Buy Milk And Bread')

todo.subscribe(function(update){ // or todo.subscribe.once

  update.add
  // => { 0: 'Buy Milk And Bread', 1: 'Cook Dinner' }

  update.remove
  // => [0, 1]

})
```