# Can I add array accessors to generic TypeScript classes?

Tags: arrays, list, generics, typescript

I have a list class that looks like this:

```
class List<T> {
    private _array: Array<T>;

    constructor() {
        this._array = new Array<T>();
    }

    get count() { return this._array.length; }

    public add = (state) => {
        this._array.push(state);
    }
    ...
}
```

And I would like to access the internal array from the class:

```
var something = list[0];
```

In c# I would do it something like this:

```
public T this[int index]
    {
        get
        {
            return _array[index];
        }
        private set {}
    }
}
```

But I can't see anyway to accomplish this in TypeScript. Is there a way to add array accessors to my class so it looks more like a generic List ?

Thanks for the brainpower!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can though the syntax is a bit weird. Note that since typescript gets compiled to js, only numbers and strings are valid keys:

```
interface IList<T> {
    [index: number]: T
}

interface IMap<T> {
    [index: string]: T
}

interface IMap<K, V> {
    [index: K]: V // Error: Index signature parameter type must be either string or number
}
```

There's a trick to it though. You can't actually overload the operator, you can only tell the compiler that it *exists*. For instance if you have a generic object that you wish to use as a hashtable - declare it as `Map<T>` instead of `any`. The same goes for arrays.

The only possible way to actually put the operator in good use is to use an array or object as the underlying element, declare them as `IList/IMap` and then fiddle with their properties / prototype to add specific functionality. For example, to create an observable array see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5100376/how-to-watch-for-array-changes)

Comment: Okay, I will have to try again because I tried your first answer before asking the question but got an empty result from the list. With var a = list[0] 'a' was undefined. I will try it again as soon as I can. Thanks for the quick response!

Comment: After testing in the playground I think it might be my way of thinking about it that is wrong. The index goes on 'this'. So, I can add and retrieve things using an array style index (list[i]). However, I thought I would need an array property to store the data. Without that, I am not sure how to do things like splice and normal Javascript array handling. Any good examples out there you could point me to? Thanks Nikola!

Comment: I might have exaggerated with my answer. The thing is that since JS doesn't allow for operator overloading and Typescript is striving to be a superset of JS, Typescript can't allow operator overloading either (well, at least for now, in the future they may compile operators as function like __operator_index). The code I showed you above is not useful in building your own container (sorry for misleading you) but it is useful when you *already* have a container and you'd like to use it instead of a `any`. I'll edit my answer to make it clearer.