# js track array length

Tags: javascript, arrays

target is to track array changes (based on length).

i found solution to one part of it, and i'm in trouble with second:

```js
var arr = Object.create([])
  , _length = 0
  ;

Object.defineProperty(arr, 'length', {
    enumerable: true,
    get: function () {
        return _length;
    },
    set: function (length) {
        //TODO: you can compare and do some action here
        _length = length;
    }
});
```

maybe this would be useful for you, as this will track all changes made to arr, using Array methods (push, pop, shift...)

but here i came to second part: if you use index to assign some values, like

```js
arr[0] = 1;
```

this wouldn't work: length stay same, and tracking is not working =(

so could anyone help me?

added:
ok, MDN tells us:

> When setting a property on a JavaScript array when the property is a
>   valid array index and that index is outside the current bounds of the
>   array, the engine will update the array's length property accordingly

does anyone know, how does this happens???

i sense, that this newly created arr must be instance of Array, so seems like i must do something like [this](http://perfectionkills.com/how-ecmascript-5-still-does-not-allow-to-subclass-an-array/#wrappers_direct_property_injection).

added x2:

```js
var _length = 0
  , arr = Object.create(Array.prototype, {
  length: {
   enumerable: true,
   get: function () {
    return _length;
   },
   set: function (length) {
    console.log('[debug] newLength/oldLength: ', length+'/'+_length);
    _length = length;
   }
  }
 })
  ;
```

now arr is instance of Array (arr instanceof Array -> true), but still arr[0] = 1 wouldn't trigger length setter =(

Comment: btw: Array.isArray(arr) will return false (obviously), but for my case this is ok.

Comment: I am trying to understand what your actual goal is here? Perhaps you could explain a little further?

Comment: Your query will have to be a function of the length of the array you need to know about, there is no solution which encapsulates the functionality you think you require.

Comment: @Xotic750 i want to have native watcher over array length, that will do something on array length change

Comment: If your target is to track array changes based on length, your code works. If you want to track when existing items are modified, you're in for a whole lot of fun, and it is very likely to only work for your use case

Comment: @JuanMendes thanks, i know =)
but imagine something like that:
arr.push(2);
arr.unshift(1);
arr.pop();
arr.shift();
arr[0]=1;

first 4 - work great, but fifth - nope =(
and, no, track changes to EXISTING elements is not what i want, while insert of new elements using index is the case.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, then you want to sub-class an array and add a length watcher. What you have presently, is not a sub-classed array. You will need to use ES6 [`classes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes) to be able to do this. I don't think you can do what you want in ES5.

Comment: @Xotic750 yeap, this is the way, but i want to stay in ES5

Comment: Then I'm afraid you are out of luck.

Comment: @Xotic750 I still have hope =)

Comment: You could also try ES6 [`proxy`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy), but again it's not ES5. FireFox has [Object.watch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/watch) which is non-standard and Chrome/Opera were working on [Object.observe](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/observe) again non-standard

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5100376/how-to-watch-for-array-changes)

It explains a few options that you might be interested in.

#2 seems like a good candidate for what you're looking for.

Comment: nope, there, when he do "x[2] = 'foo';" x already have defined property "2" for objet "x" and tracks it.
my interest is to track if item was added (there was no such index before)
+ updated original post
anyway - thank you =)

Comment: @AndrewKazman if none of those answers work for you then you will have to wait for the technology to advance far enough to make it work. You can definitely be hopeful for that :) but for now, you might as well figure something else out.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have some fun, there is a [spec for observables objects/arrays](http://arv.github.io/ecmascript-object-observe/) or you can use [underscore](http://documentcloud.github.io/underscore/)/[lodash](https://lodash.com/) (they are interchangeable) and an extension: https://github.com/mennovanslooten/underscore-observe It's easy to use:

```
_.observe(some_array, function(new_array, old_array) { /* called for every change */ });
```

Comment: Both, underscore and lodash, observe is based on setInterval (timeout ~250 as i can remember) - this is not good option (+ it is really simple to make watcher based on setInterval without any additional libs)

Comment: It doesn't use setInterval anymore, it redefines the built-in array methods, [code source here](https://github.com/mennovanslooten/underscore-observe).

Comment: https://github.com/mennovanslooten/underscore-observe/blob/master/underscore-observe.js#L326 - seems like they have same problem as i: all is working till you assign value using index