# How to add a new div element to DOM dynamically each time I push a new object in an Array?

Tags: angular, angular2-template

Assume there is an empty array. Whenever anything is pushed in that array then I want to create a new div element in that component and immediately display it in the DOM.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5100376/how-to-watch-for-array-changes

Comment: Following Stav Alfi's answer, angular `watch`es changes in the scope variables. If you create an `ngFor`, and use your array as the source, every time the array is going to change (amount of items or content of items), the `DOM` will update accordingly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ng-For for creating and display divs as soon as you push new data to the array. I assuming all the array cells has the same data type so its easy to display their data:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of array">
  {{item.name}}
</div>
```