# How to recursively trap all changes to an object?

Tags: javascript

I'm using a Proxy to detect when an object is modified (and then I save it to disk). This works great for simple properties of the proxied object, but fails on modification of object properties.

```
var obj = {
  p1 = "Hello",
  a1 = []
}

var dirtyHandler = {
    set: function(obj, prop, value) {
        markDirty(obj);
        obj[prop] = value;
        return true;
    }
};

var proxied = new Proxy(obj, dirtyHandler);
proxied.p1 = "World"; // <-- proxy detects modification
proxied.a1.push({'foo': 3}); // <-- proxy does not detect modification
```

Does anyone know how to recursively detect any modification in my object (a1.push(...), a1[0].foo = 4, etc.)?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5100376/how-to-watch-for-array-changes

Comment: Make a proxy for the array as well? Possibly dynamically on getting an arbitrary property?

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I ended up solving this for my use case.

First I add a proxy for all the known objects I care about (not shown). In the handler for the proxy on every set call I check if the value is already a proxy and if not, substitute one:

```
var DirtyHandler = function(root) {
    this.root = root;

    this.set = (obj, prop, value) => {
        if (!dirtyIgnores[prop]) {
            debug('Dirty: ' + prop + ' of ' + obj.commitId);
            markDirty(this.root);
        }
        if (value && typeof value === 'object') {
            value = new Proxy(value, this);
        }
        obj[prop] = value;
        return true;
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I published a library on GitHub (**[Observable Slim](https://github.com/ElliotNB/observable-slim)**) that recursively iterates through a target object and applies a Proxy on all objects. It enables you to monitor all changes that occur under a single target object no matter how deeply nested they are. It also has a few extra features:

- Reports back to a specified callback whenever changes occur.
- Will prevent user from trying to Proxy a Proxy.
- Keeps a store of which objects have been proxied and will re-use existing proxies instead of creating new ones (very significant performance implications).
- Allows user to traverse up from a child object and retrieve the parent.
- Written in ES5 and plays nice with the [Proxy Polyfill](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/proxy-polyfill) so it can be deployed in older browsers fairly easily.

Please feel free to take a look and hopefully contribute as well!