# Run a function in javascript when an array is being "written" or "read"

Tags: javascript, arrays, local-storage, event-listener, alasql

I have an array (actually the database data from `alasql` [on github](https://github.com/agershun/alasql)), and I want to run a function when it is "written" or "read" in script.

"written" stands for `push`, `pull` and **Assignment operator** like `=`,

While "read" stands for direct access to the array value like `array` (whole array), `array[0]` (an element of the array) etc., and reading properties like `array.length`

Actually I use those function for accessing the `localStorage`.

I have already read [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5100376/how-to-watch-for-array-changes) but I still don't have my own solution since I have a few restrictions here.

1. I have to monitor not just `push()` but `=` so ***Override the push method*** does not work for me.
2. That array is actually created by the javascript library `alasql` and I am not going to change the library code since it can be a big big task, so ***Create a custom observable array*** is not possible.
3. The library access the array directly for SQL statements as the store the data of the SQL table, so it is impossible to use ***proxy***.
4. My script is going to run on a `firefox` on a slow computer running xp bought at least 10 years ago with hardware like < 1GB RAM and single-core CPU, and the array which is actually the SQL table will have entries like 10000 entries, hence the array is ***performance*** required. If I use library like ***underscore-observe*** [on github](https://github.com/mennovanslooten/underscore-observe), which relies on scanning every 250ms, that dumb computer will simply die.
5. Use ***smart-collection*** [on github](https://github.com/mgesmundo/smart-collection). Well, I actually don't know what does [that answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28236769) and the readme on github talking about, but I don't think it will works since I have to create another array for it (?)
6. Use ***localStorage*** engine of `alasql` [on github readme](https://github.com/agershun/alasql#localstorage-and-dom-storage), fine, this could be the best one initially and I tried it. But I decided to left it when I found a [bug](https://github.com/agershun/alasql/issues/774) of it which block my work.

I would be glad if someone can give me a solution on how to do the trick, since it is a main and big issue in my project so far.

P.S.: My project is to develop a single HTML page that run a POS-like system with sell and borrow functionality with SQL, and It is going to run in a dumb old computer without internet connection.

Comment: I think you want proxies.

Comment: @torazaburo I tried it and found it unusuable since I have to acess the array using the proxy, which the sql intreputer will not do so.

Comment: Re: your point #2 : could you point out the code responsible for this, specifically, in that repo? (not familiar with it, here)

Comment: So do I. I have just met this library for one week, so I did not even look at the source code of it. But to use the "create an observable array" u have to generate a new custom array with a custom constructor, which should not be possible without big change on the library code, so I am preventing it and looking for suck a better solution possible

Comment: Maybe edit that last comment and remove the word "suck".

Comment: You have two ways of establishing this. **a)** You have to subclass your array and define a getter and setter for it's length property so that each time it's touched you will have your function piggy backed in the getter / setter running. **b)** You have to use the proxy object.

Comment: sorry fot the typo of "suck", it is "such" in face but I cannot edit it now @trincot

Comment: a): I could have my content changed without length changed, or would you like to do some example? b): I tried proxy but it seems that it will not function if you don't interact with the item using proxy right? @Redu

Comment: Even if you don't change the length of the array, even if you simply access the array, the `length` property is checked so we can use it to make the array observable. But then once you detect that your array has been touched, to find out the changes you need to do some clever array diffing. I will insert an answer demonstrating this functionality later today once i have sometime.

Comment: thank you for your help @Redu, waiting for your answer to come