# How to watch for object changes?

Tags: javascript, object, watch, changeset

Using this example: [How to watch for array changes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5100376/how-to-watch-for-array-changes) i tried to adapt to watch for object chabges:

```
(function() {

  if (!("Proxy" in window)) {
    console.warn("Your browser doesn't support Proxies.");
    return;
  }

  var ob = {"a":["a", "b", "c", "d"]};

  // a proxy for our ob
  var proxy = new Proxy(ob, {
    apply: function(target, thisArg, argumentsList) {
      return thisArg[target].apply(this, argumentList);
    },
    deleteProperty: function(target, property) {
      console.log("Deleted %s", property);
      return true;
    },
    set: function(target, property, value, receiver) {      
      target[property] = value;
      console.log("Set %s to %o", property, value);
      return true;
    }
  });
proxy.a.push("z");

  console.log("Current state of array: %o", ob);

})();
```

But the push does not trigger the console.log in set. Only if i change:

```
var proxy = new Proxy(ob.a, {...
proxy.push("z");
```

Can anyone help me? Thank you

Comment: You want to watch the array or the object ? Pushing on the array won't trigger the setter in the object. They are different object.

Comment: i want to watch the object. The array inside the ob.a is just an example.

Comment: Then you have to do another Proxy on the array and in apply check to see if the target is push then log it.

Comment: So if the object has several properties and the value of each one is a array, i need to create a proxy for each property?

Comment: Your code work with the obj look at this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mjaz3fLz/)

Comment: You can recursively proxify values if they object or array in the setter.

Comment: T4rk1n, that works. So simple. Thank you.