# Trigger set() when adding element to array

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript

I am attempting to manage an array within an Angular service like so:

```
import { TodoItem } from '../models/todo-item.model';

@Injectable()
export class TodoService {
  //local storage key name
  private readonly lsKey = 'pi-todo';
  private _todos: Array<TodoItem>;

  //Gets the todo items from local storage
  public fetchTodos(): Array<TodoItem> {
    //Either get the items if they exist, or get an empty array
    this.todos = (JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(this.lsKey)) as Array<TodoItem>) || [];

    return this.todos;
  }

  //Adds the todo item to local storage
  public addTodo(todo: TodoItem): Array<TodoItem> {
    if (todo) {
      //Better way to do this?
      let tempTodos = this.todos;
      tempTodos.push(
        Object.assign(
          {
            completed: false
          },
          todo
        )
      );

      this.todos = tempTodos;

      return this.todos;
    }
  }


  private get todos(): Array<TodoItem> {
    return this._todos || [];
  }

  private set todos(todos: Array<TodoItem>) {
    this._todos = todos;
    localStorage.setItem(this.lsKey, JSON.stringify(this._todos));
  }
}
```

When adding a todo item to the `todos` array, I tried doing `this.todos.push(...);` but then that doesn't trigger the `setter`. How can I do this without using a temp array?

Comment: Might be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5100376/how-to-watch-for-array-changes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest moving the "save to local storage" code to a separate method called by both the setter and the add.

```
  //Adds the todo item to local storage
  public addTodo(todo: TodoItem): Array<TodoItem> {
    if (todo) {
      this.todos.push(
        Object.assign(
          {
            completed: false
          },
          todo
        )
      );

      this.save();
      return this.todos;
    }
  }

  private set todos(todos: Array<TodoItem>) {
    this._todos = todos;
    this.save();
  }

  private save() {
     localStorage.setItem(this.lsKey, JSON.stringify(this._todos));
  }
```

Comment: Smart. Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

Yes, because you aren't setting it a new value. A work around would be this: instead of pushing into the array, grab the current array, assign it to a temp variable, then replace with new array. Like so:

```
triggerSet(newValue) {
   const tempArray = this.todos;
    tempArray.push(newValue);
     this.todos = tempArray;
}
```