# How to store the value of an object within an array before it changes?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Assume the following array:

```js
var arr = [0,0,{x:0,y:0}];
var newA = arr.slice(0); 
arr[2].x =2; 
arr[2].y =2;
console.log(newA)
```

x and y are coordinates that are supposed to be changed. How can I store them before a function is invoked and they change (perhaps pushing to a new array)? A shallow copy with slice won't work as the copied array will update the values dynamically.

Comment: Make a JSON string and reparse.

Comment: Question is not very clear. Give an example of what problem you are facing through code.

Comment: [Please, do more research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) then **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't** working and provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read [How to Ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Be sure to [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/347937/im-new-to-stack-overflow-what-are-some-things-i-should-do-and-what-things-wil).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to watch for array changes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5100376/how-to-watch-for-array-changes)

Comment: I don't know have this couldn't have been more clear. So assume the following:

var arr = [0,0,{x:0,y:0}];
var newA = arr.slice(0);

arr[2].x =2;
arr[2].y =2;

Now both arr and newA have the object coordinates x and y updated. I would like to store the newA x and y coordinates after the initial array i.e. arr has been changed

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Copying array by value in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7486085/copying-array-by-value-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) to duplicate the object without creating a reference.

For example:

```
var arr = [0,0,{x:0,y:0}];
var bak = Object.assign({}, arr[2])
```

In this case, `bak` is *not* a reference to `arr[2]`, so changing either would not affect the other.