# How to execute .js only if array length changes

Tags: javascript, highcharts

https://jsfiddle.net/648vpa40/

My code is as follows.
What I wanna do is to draw picture only if array `btc_price` changes.
To do so I added this part:

```
function draw() {
            console.log("draw picture");
            print_chart(btc_price);
        }

        if (a != b) {
            draw();
        } else {
            console.log("nothing to do");
        }
```

Where a and b are lengths of btc_price obtained in 2 different if's.
But it never helps me.
What's wrong with my code?

Comment: THis may help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5100376/how-to-watch-for-array-changes

Comment: @brk great, thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to watch for array changes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5100376/how-to-watch-for-array-changes)