# How to check if all array values are blank in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array like:

```
["", "", "", "1", "", ""]
```

I want to alert when all the array values are `blanks`, i.e, when the array is like this:

```
["", "", "", "", "", ""]
```

How can I achieve this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to watch for array changes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5100376/how-to-watch-for-array-changes)

Comment: How is it a duplicate @Faisal?

Comment: I think the description is more suited to describe observable arrays.

Comment: But it is not be duplicate @Faizal.

Comment: Erm...the above doesn't need to observe anything @Faisal

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can always use a basic `for` loop as a solution for your problem:

```js
function allBlanks(arr)
{
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
    {
        if (arr[i] !== "") return false;
    }

    return true;
}

console.log(allBlanks(["", "", "", "1", "", ""]));
console.log(allBlanks(["", "", "", "", "", ""]));
console.log(allBlanks(["", [], "", null, undefined, ""]));
```

```css
.as-console {background-color:black !important; color:lime;}
.as-console-wrapper {max-height:100% !important; top:0;}
```

Answer (score 12):

Use `every()`:

```js
const allEmpty = arr => arr.every(e => e === "");
console.log(allEmpty(["", "", "", "1", "", ""]));
console.log(allEmpty(["", "", "", "", "", ""]));
```

Comment: Just out of curiousity: is it better to use `==` or `===` for this case, or does it not really matter at all?

Comment: Whoops - I missed that @Terry. Thanks! It's better to use `===` because if an array element is `0`, then it'll be removed (because `0 == ""`). Try it - it evaluates to true! (Weird, I know - but they both evaluate to `false`)

Answer (score 11):

Try this,

```
["", "", "", "", "", ""].join("").length==0
```

If you want to remove spaces,

```
["", "", "", "", "", ""].join("").replace(/\s/gi,'').length==0
```

Note :

This will not work for inputs like  `["", [], "", null, undefined, ""]`

Comment: You can also `trim()` if there are spaces in the array :)

Comment: `array.join("").replace(/\s/gi,'').length==0` will be improved version of this answer.

Comment: I dont want to trim because that blank values i have to use

Comment: I hope he wasn't worried about spaces , updated the answer anyway. @VikashSingh

Comment: Note this will returns `true` for an input like: `["", [], "", null, undefined, ""]`. If you are strictly looking that all items are empty strings `""` then this won't be good.

Comment: Agree @Shidersz but his question is about empty strings , his requirements are clear. My answer is to solve his problem. Will update the answer so it may help someone.

Comment: @SrinivasanSekar Yeah, never said your answer was wrong, thats is why I marked my comment as a `note`. Just to warn the OP about the situation.

Comment: ok i'll look into this. and as soon as its work i'll accept the answer

Answer (score 6):

###### TL;DR (Fastest & Simple)

```js
[].some(Boolean)  //  Empty : false   |   Not Empty : true
```

###### Explanation

Mixture of native functions, [`Boolean`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Boolean) with [`.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) or [`.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) or using [`.join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) can return the expected result:

```js
var a=['','','','',''],   // Empty
    b=['','','x','',''];  // Not Empty

// Is Not Empty?

// #1
console.log( a.some(Boolean) ); // false
console.log( b.some(Boolean) ); // true

// #2
console.log( a.filter(Boolean).length ); // = 0
console.log( b.filter(Boolean).length ); // != 0

// #3
console.log( a.join('')!='' ); // false
console.log( b.join('')!='' ); // true
```

Also a user-defined function:

```js
var a=['','','','',''],   // Empty
    b=['','','x','',''];  // Not Empty
        
function isArrayEmpty(a) { 
  for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) 
    if (a[i]) return false;
  return true;
}

console.log( isArrayEmpty(a) ); // true
console.log( isArrayEmpty(b) ); // false
```

But about **performance**:

1. `.some(Boolean)` ~40M ops/s *(Operation per second)*
2. `isArrayEmpty()` ~36M ops/s *(~10% slower)*
3. `.filter(Boolean).length` ~9M ops/s *(~75% slower)*
4. `.join('')!=''` ~4M ops/s *(~90% slower)*

**Note (1):** Using [Arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) `(a)=>a` instead of Boolean, will make the performances even lower, in these cases about ~5% slower.

**Note (2):** The expected result is same just when we are sure that all of array items are *String*. About other [falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) s (`null` or `false` ...) items, the option #3 (join) will not work.

Comment: Easily the best answer here. This should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 3):

Here is also a more generic approach which would `compact` the array removing all `falsey` values and then check the remaining length:

```js
let compact = a => a.reduce((r,c) => (!!c ? r.push(c) : null, r),[])

let isEmpty = array => compact(array).length == 0

console.log(isEmpty(["", false, 0, "", null, undefined])) // true
console.log(isEmpty(["", 1]))   // false
console.log(isEmpty(["", []]))  // false
console.log(isEmpty(["", {}]))  // false
```

But if this is the only use case you care about then you can also use  [Array.some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some):

```js
let isEmpty = a => !a.some(x => x !== '')

// OR let isEmpty = a => !a.some(x => x.toString().length > 0)

console.log(isEmpty(["", "", "", "", "", ""]))
console.log(isEmpty(["", "", "1", "", "", ""]))
```

You could also use [Array.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce):

```js
let isEmpty = a => !a.reduce((r,c) => `${r}${c}`).length

console.log(isEmpty(["", "", "", "", "", ""]))
console.log(isEmpty(["", "", "1", "", "", ""]))
```

[Array.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter):

```js
let isEmpty = a => !a.filter(x => x.toString().length).length

console.log(isEmpty(["", "", "", "", "", ""]))
console.log(isEmpty(["", "", "1", "", "", ""]))
```

This will only be valid check against your current input however. Not against cases with arrays, object literals etc as part of your input array.

---

If you are using `lodash` this could be (via [`_.every`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#every) and [`_.isEmpty`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#isEmpty)):

```js
let isArrayEmpty = a => _.every(a, _.isEmpty)

console.log(isArrayEmpty(["", "", "", "", "", ""]))
console.log(isArrayEmpty(["", "", "1", "", "", ""]))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

or also via [`_.compact`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#compact) which also removes falsey values:

```js
let isArrayEmpty = a => !_.compact(a).length

console.log(isArrayEmpty(["", "", "", "", "", ""]))
console.log(isArrayEmpty(["", "", "1", "", "", ""]))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks man
Accepted one throws undefined

Answer (score 1):

```js
const isEmpty=arr=>{
  return arr.filter(it=>it.length>0).length ==0
}

arr1 = ["",""]
arr2 = ["1",""]

console.log(isEmpty(arr1))
console.log(isEmpty(arr2))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var arr1 = ["", "", "", "1", "", ""];
var arr2 = ["", "", "", "", "", ""];

function checkArrValEmpty(arr) {
  let count = 0;
  for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if(arr[i].trim().length === 0) {`enter code here`
      count++;
    }
  }
  return count === arr.length
}

console.log(checkArrValEmpty(arr2));
console.log(checkArrValEmpty(arr1));
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
function isEmpty (arr){
  return arr.every(e => e === "")
};
let a = ["", "", "", "1", "", ""];
let b = ["", "", "", "", "", ""] 
console.log(isEmpty(a));
console.log(isEmpty(b));
```

Answer (score 1):

I implemented small function for checking empty array which will work in all browsers.

```js
var list=["1", [], "", null, undefined, ""];
var listE=["", "", "","", "", "", ""];
var listE1=["", [], "", null, undefined, ""];

function isArrayEmpty(arr){
return arr.toString().replace(/,/g, '')=="";
}

alert(isArrayEmpty(list))
alert(isArrayEmpty(listE))
alert(isArrayEmpty(listE1))
```

Answer (score 1):

1) Maintain the size of array as length 
2) Find the no. of empty values in the array and store it in say an variable (EmptyValues) 
3) Check if (EmptyValue== length)  {  Give Alert whatever you want}

```
function checkBlankvalues(arr){
var emptyValues=0,length=arr.length;
//for finding empty vales in array till now
for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++)
{ 
   if(arr[i]="")
   {
     emptyValues++;
   }
}
if(length==emptyValue)
{
 //alert("array is blank");
}
}
```