# check all arrays of array are empty in array of arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I have an array with a length of 12. how can I check all the arrays of the array are empty?

```
let array = [[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[]]
```

Comment: Would `array.every(arr => arr.length < 1)` work?

Comment: Another way could be to flatten and check the length: `arr.flat().length == 0`

Comment: `array.join('') === ""`

Comment: Duplicate (some transfer needed...!): [How to check if all array values are blank in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56319699/how-to-check-if-all-array-values-are-blank-in-javascript)

Comment: @georg not if there's an empty string somewhere inside

Comment: @JonasWilms: obviously, the question is about arrays of arrays specifically.

Comment: @georg but what do the arrays of arrays contain? We don't know that yet ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On each element, you could do a strict check with [`Array.isArray`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/isArray) (to avoid empty string `""` and object `{length: 0}`) and then check its length

```js
const array = [[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[]]
const falseArray1 = [[1],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[]]
const falseArray2 = ["",[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[]]
const falseArray3 = [{length:0},[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[]]


const isValid = arrayOfArray => arrayOfArray.every(arr => Array.isArray(arr) && arr.length === 0)

console.log(isValid(array))
console.log(isValid(falseArray1))
console.log(isValid(falseArray2))
console.log(isValid(falseArray3))
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to iterate through [every](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) array and checks if all the sub-arrays are empty

```
array.every(subArr => subArr.length === 0)
```

Comment: Please don't post an answer if the answer is a link to the docs and a single line of code. Stackoverflow is primarily about creating an exhaustive FAQ of common programming problems, not about rehashing the docs to beginners.

Comment: I'm explaining that he needs to iterate through his array and using the every function ( which I gently give the doc link for him to check if he doesn't know ... ) I'm not "rehashing" anything ... Sorry to try to help ... At least I'm not here just to criticize...

Comment: Neither am I. I'm just explaining my downvote. Helping people is fine obviously, but you can do that in a comment.

Comment: Good point that at least you did ... Because I didn't get it for sur ....
Look at the first comment that already has 4 upvote ... But still is more concise that my answer is....

Comment: Don't take it personal; people with 10k rep are posting answers to this even though it's a very probable duplicate and indeed turned out to be one.

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest approach would be to create a function, i,e:

```
function checkEmpty(array) {
  return Array.isArray(array) && (array.length == 0 || array.every(isEmpty));
}
```

You can then test which arrays you'd like. For example:

```
console.log(checkEmpty([[], [[]]]));
```

Output:

```
true
```

You can then use this boolean value to your advantage and work with anything else you'd like.