# detect onPositionChanged for multiple elements from array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

am trying to use .onPositionChanged for multiple elements that I pushed into an array. this array keeps updating each time I click on an element.

array example in the screenshot.
[array screenshot](http://munzo.me/array.png)

so what am trying to achieve here is when the user clicks on an element we push it into an array and we want to keep checking for any position changes.

this is my function

```
        jQuery.fn.onPositionChanged = function (trigger, millis) {
            if (millis == null) millis = 10;
            var o = $(this[0]); // our jquery object
            if (o.length < 1) return o;

            var lastPos = null;
            var lastOff = null;
            setInterval(function () {
                if (o == null || o.length < 1) return o; // abort if element is non existend eny more
                if (lastPos == null) lastPos = o.position();
                if (lastOff == null) lastOff = o.offset();
                var newPos = o.position();
                var newOff = o.offset();
                if (lastPos.top != newPos.top || lastPos.left != newPos.left) {
                    $(this).trigger('onPositionChanged', {
                        lastPos: lastPos,
                        newPos: newPos
                    });
                    if (typeof (trigger) == "function") trigger(lastPos, newPos);
                    lastPos = o.position();
                }
                if (lastOff.top != newOff.top || lastOff.left != newOff.left) {
                    $(this).trigger('onOffsetChanged', {
                        lastOff: lastOff,
                        newOff: newOff
                    });
                    if (typeof (trigger) == "function") trigger(lastOff, newOff);
                    lastOff = o.offset();
                }
            }, millis);

            return o;
        };


    $(ele).onPositionChanged(function(e) {
    ele.offset().left
    });
```

this is a working example for a single specific element. but I want to achieve it as described above.

I was struggling for a long time, I wish anyone can help.

thank you in advanced

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using timers to watch for changes, use the standard Observer pattern to be notified of changes in your array.

The below answer gives you an implementation of an ObservableArray (section 2). To use it in your code, replace your Array instances with ObservableArray instances and implement the appropriate event listeners for the events that you need (itemadded, itemset, itemremoved, etc.):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/5100420/14239018