# How to update an array elements without console.log it again?

Tags: javascript

lets say we have

```
let nums = [
[1 , 2],
[3 , 4]
] 
console.log(nums)
document.addEventListener('keydown', (event) => {
    if (event.code == "Numpad7"){
       nums[0][1] = 5;
    } 
  })
```

So now I want to change the "4" to 5
I do the reassignment `nums[0][1] = 5`
but this doesnt actually update the already consoled.log printed array.
Is there a way for this?

Comment: Chrome has this option
https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript/watch-variables
Firefox too

Comment: @Areu so anything inside the code wont do ?

Comment: Are we talking node.js? Because in the browser, this already works as expected, given that console output is live.

Comment: You're logging `nums` but updating `cells`

Comment: I tried this code (after fixing it), and if the array view is expanded after the keypress, it shows the new value. However, the real question is: what is the point? What is your end goal here?

Comment: yes @ChrisG, the value indeed changed but I need the 1st printed Array to update , not print again
Goal is a tic tac toe XD

Comment: Right, in that case output and update the array in the document / browser view, not the console.

Comment: If you want the console to only display the current state of your array, then use `console.clear()` to remove existing entries and do a new `console.log(nums)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can clear the console log and Then log the new value.

```
   let nums = [
    [1 , 2],
    [3 , 4]
    ] 
    console.log(nums)
    document.addEventListener('keydown', (event) => {
        if (event.code == "Numpad7"){
           nums[1][1] = 5;
           console.clear();
           console.log(nums);
        } 
      })
```

Answer (score 1):

Console.log logs the value of variable in it's current state.
If you want to log the updated version of the array, you have to log it after updating.

Comment: yes i thought of that but the boarder needs to always be there as , the function I did was that when I press number 1 , it changed the the number 4 to 5, so print again when the variable is changed when given input wont really work

Comment: @Extraordinary here is your answer. You have to log the array again after updating it

Comment: @Rilla thats not the code is set up to be , it should update when I press a button

Comment: @Extraordinary from the code in your question changing 4 to 5 would work fine. You can add a console.log to log the nums array after the update in your event listener

Comment: So when you press the numeric key 7, it console.log nums after changing 4 to 5

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to reassign the value is:

```
nums[1][1] = 5
```

Comment: thanks tho XD
Its a little different from what i need

Comment: This isn't an answer to the question though, please remove this

Answer (score 0):

Most versions of Chrome will auto-update objects so if you wrap your result in an object you might get what you're after.

```js
var x = {attrib:"hello"}
console.log(x);
x.attrib = "world";
//check browswer console - not the Stack Overflow preview.
```

Answer (score 0):

So thanks u guys for your help so I had to put console.log inside the function , even tho it isnt quiet what I wanted, ill look into it :)

Comment: If you do not have to support older browsers, I think what you wanted to achieve can be done using a [Proxy object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy). There is a short explanation with an implementation example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5100420/14201528)