# Dropdown list in textbox that can change with array

Tags: javascript, html

in advanced, I am a beginner trying to learn how to create a website using HTML, CSS and Javascript.

My situation is the following:

I have an array of strings and a textfield (input). I want to make the textfield have a dropdown menu (like datalist) but I want to have the options in the dropdown menu change when the array changes.

Example:

Array has: ['Example 1', 'Example 2', 'Example 3']
Dropdown menu shows: 'Example 1', 'Example 2', 'Example 3'

Array changes to: ['Example 1', 'Example 2', 'Example 3', 'Example 4']
Dropdown menu shows: 'Example 1', 'Example 2', 'Example 3', 'Example 4'

Thank you in advanced for any comments.

Comment: if you want to use regular arrays, I guess the furthest you can go is overriding their push method to observe when any element gets added and call it an event you would be listening for to update your dropdown options. But since transforms like slice for example actually return a new shallow copy, those wouldn't be tracked. So probably a whole collection wrapper could be a better deal. Here some hints: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5100376/how-to-watch-for-array-changes

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I just used regular arrays since its the only thing I knew. If you have any other hints for me, which I could try to use / research about, please let me know. I am open for any other ideas.

Comment: Sometimes it's just better to keep it simple. As long as I could read on your question, the change you are expecting is the addition of elements. That scenario will be easily solved by the solution suggested in my first comment. The event I was talking about could be just a call to a function that will update the dropdown. Anyway unless this is an exercise to test your skills, I would suggest to do it differently. Can't you just have a function that refresh the dropdown options given an array? so that everytime you change the array you also refresh the dropdown

Comment: Now you mention it, that would actually be much easier to do. I will try that out, thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

You can try by following way, using DOM methods.

```js
(function() {

  // Get select element
  const selectEl = document.getElementById("select-example");

  // optionsArray
  const optionsArr = ["Example-1", "Example-2", "Example-3", "Example-4"];

  /*
  - Loop over optionsArr
  - Create new option element & attach text
  - Append above created option element to select element
  */
  for (optionText of optionsArr) {
    const optionEl = document.createElement("option");
    optionEl.innerText = optionText;
    selectEl.appendChild(optionEl);
  }
})();
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <select name="select-example" id="select-example">
    <option disable>Select example</option>
  </select>
</div>
```