# Simultaneous Writing and Reading of data using Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-chrome-extension, socket.io

I am developing a Chrome extension that communicates with a remote API via a WebSocket connection using Socket.io. The API sends me streaming data in string format. My goal is to hold the streaming data in a buffer for a few seconds until I receive a specific message from the content script. Once the message "startStreaming" is received, I want to start streaming the data to the content script.

To achieve this, I am thinking to use a buffer array to store the incoming data from the server. E.g

```js
let buffer = [];

socket.on('stream', (wordChunk) => {
    buffer.push(wordChunk);
});

if (msg.msg === 'startStreaming') {
    console.log('Send response back to Tab');
    buffer.forEach(wordChunk => {
        port.postMessage({ msg: 'streamData', wordChunk });
    });
}
```

But the problem I am facing is ensuring the simultaneous writing and reading of data in a safe manner. Since the data can be continuously streamed from the server while the buffer is being read and processed, I need to handle this situation properly to avoid any data inconsistencies.

I would greatly appreciate any suggestions or best practices on how to handle this scenario effectively, ensuring that the data is read in the FIFO (First-In, First-Out) order and avoiding any race conditions or data corruption issues.

Suggest me if there is any other way rather than array.

**Scenario**
If we don't take Chrome Extension to the context, think it in such a way that, I want to pre-fetch api response before a user's action. E.g I want to start fetching data from the server and store it temporarily when a user just hover over the button. And display the response instantly when he clicks on the button to make him feel that it is super fast. So we don't know when the user clicks on the button, as soon as he hovers or after few times of hovering the button.

Thank you in advance for your assistance!

Comment: I think this gets you what you want here https://stackoverflow.com/q/5100376/125981

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this might be a good candidate for a [ReplaySubject](https://rxjs.dev/guide/subject#replaysubject) from RXJS.

I've put an example below on how it **could** work in your situation, but in practice I wouldn't recommend the interval thing. It is only to demonstrate based on your code.

```
import { ReplaySubject } from "rxjs";

const subject = new ReplaySubject<any>()

socket.on('stream', wordChunk => {
  subject.next(wordChunk);
});

const interval = setInterval(() => {
  if(msg.msg === 'startStreaming') {
    subject.subscribe({
      next: (wordChunk) => port.postMessage({ msg: 'streamData', wordChunk })
    })
    clearInterval(interval);
  };
}, 1000);
```

I've built a [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/intelligent-framework-iwm9l3?file=/src/index.ts) to show a `ReplaySubject` in action.

Comment: Awesome. It is working. But I will do few more test before marking it accepted.

Comment: It's worth reading up on Observables if this is your first time using them, ensuring that you are cleaning up correctly and handling errors. I'm glad I could help.

Comment: Do I need to clean this ReplaySubject as well? I am not familiar with rxjx. Could you give some hints please?

Comment: I wouldn't worry about it too much. You can unsubscribe from a subject when you don't want to listen any more. If you call `subject.error` it will stop future `subject.next` calls. You can also stop the subject by calling `subject.complete`. You can listen to those two events in your subscribe call like `subject.subscribe({next: (value) => {}. error: (error) => {}, complete: () => {}})`. You can also set limits on the size and time of the buffer (subject). Everything is in the link in the answer.

Comment: You don't need to accept this answer right away. There may be better answers out there.

Answer (score 1):

Javascript code execution is single-threaded. This means your code is safe from thread interleaving issues, and the socket.on listener cannot run while the `forEach` loop is executing.

Your real issue is that the `forEach` loop will complete, and then the  socket.on listener may run afterwards. Thus, the buffer may get new entries, but the contents of the buffer will not be iterated over and sent to the port.

Here is how you could code it instead:

```js
let buffer = [];
let streamingEnabled = false;

socket.on('stream', wordChunk => {
  buffer.push(wordChunk);
  if(streamingEnabled) sendBuffer(); 
});

function sendBuffer() {
  buffer.forEach(wordChunk => port.postMessage({ msg: 'streamData', wordChunk }));
  buffer.length = 0; //clear the buffer
}

if (msg.msg === 'startStreaming') {
  streamingEnabled = true;
  sendBuffer();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for a quick tip. But the input and output are still unmatched. Few texts from streamData are missing.

Comment: @SkyRar your question did not specify how `msg` was received. Although Javascript is single-threaded, if you are using Promises/await, then the code may be executing in unexpected ways. It's impossible to diagnose without seeing more of the code

Comment: I have updated my question with a general scenario. Consider msg is user action. We don't know when the user will take the action, he may send the command at the same time when server emits the response, or after few seconds delay of server already sent the response.